# IIS not working with Windows 10

Tags: php, iis

I can retreive a simple web page but not php scripts.  I get the following message when trying to run a php script.

"there was a problem retreiving the XML Data.  Unauthorized (401).  However,  I have set all of the permissions in inetpub folder to allow access.   It's IIS after installing Windows 10 without any mods.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error,  I found that I needed to go into IIS Default Web Page and click authorization.   I then needed to enable Windows authorization.

I can now use localhost for testing web content.